# Recover LinkedIn page account

Tags: linkedin, account-recovery

I was wondering if you can help me with this. My previous coworker he open company page on LinkedIn but he is no longer with us anymore. Can I recover this page?

Noted that, I contacted with LinkedIn help center and the Expert Support told me that you should know the administrator of the page but the administrator of the page not longer with us any more and also he does not know the email and password that related with the company page.

Answer (score 2):

What help center expert said that is correct. You must be an admin of the page. As you said you don't have any information, so only LinkedIn can help you now.

[Contact LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/ask), as this is a company page, you must have company email address. Provide all the details in description section with your official email id and request them to make you admin of the page.